# Zend Framework 2 Form Erros Default Decorators

Tags: zend-framework2

How to set default form errors decorators on ZF2 ? I want set custom class on error html how to do ?

Answer (score 1):

There are no more decorators in ZF2. The thing you're looking at are called `ViewHelpers`. This is actually explained inside [the official Documentation](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.view.helpers.html#formelementerrors) (even [more than once](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#rendering)).

This would be the code you're looking at:

```
/**
 * Example #1: Default options
 */
echo $this->formElementErrors($element);
// <ul><li>Value is required and can&#039;t be empty</li></ul>

/**
 * Example #2: Add attributes to open format
 */
echo $this->formElementErrors($element, array('class' => 'help-inline'));
// <ul class="help-inline"><li>Value is required and can&#039;t be empty</li></ul>

/**
 * Example #3: Custom format
 */
echo $this->formElementErrors()
          ->setMessageOpenFormat('<div class="help-inline">')
          ->setMessageSeparatorString('</div><div class="help-inline">')
          ->setMessageCloseString('</div>')
          ->render($element);
```

This obviously is for a per-element basis.

Comment: I know that but how to set a default html format for errors ? I want to set it 1 time and not on every element

Comment: Write your own ViewHelper ;)

Answer (score 1):

As Sam said already, it would be the right way to write a new ViewHelper. But you could also call `setMessageOpenFormat()` in a Module.php file:

```
$serviceManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
$viewHelperManager = $serviceManager->get('viewhelpermanager');
$formElementErrorsViewHelper = $viewHelperManager->get('FormElementErrors');
$formElementErrorsViewHelper->setMessageOpenFormat('<div class="error"><ul%s><li>');
$formElementErrorsViewHelper->setMessageCloseString('</li></ul></div>');
```